# Using a form variable for filtering a database

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

This is my code in my `+page.server.js`:

```js
export const actions = {
    default: async ({request}) => {
        const data = await request.formData();
        const ln = data.get('lastname');
    .....
    }
};

export function load() {
    if (!db) throw error(404);

    return {
        todos: db.getTodos()
    }
}
```

My question: how do I use the actions object output variable for filtering what I get from `db.getTodos()` in the load function?

I can implement the filter on the front-end in `+page.svelte` by using a bind:value on the variable, but I would rather filter on the server side.

Comment: `load` will have an event (say, named `event`) passed in which has a `data` field which has the action result.  So in `default` return something like `{ lastname: ln }` and then in your `load` use `const { lastname } = event.data`

Comment: Thanks @emptyjar, I cannot make it work. Could you clarify a bit how to handle the event.data?

Comment: The `data` field contains data from the *server* load function, not the form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to return the correct results would be to just return them directly via the form action's data. If you want to use `load`, there are three options I can think of:

- Redirect to a URL containing the information necessary to filter
- Pass the data via a cookie
- Store the information server-side in a user session

I would not really recommend the latter two options, as they make things stateful and thus more messy.

For the redirect you can use query parameters or a different route with route parameters.
Here would be a simple example using the current route & query parameters:

```js
// +page.server.js
import { fail, redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { findResults, findId } from './db.js';

export const load = async ({ url }) => {
    const id = url.searchParams.get('id');
    const results = id == null ? null : await findResults(id);

    return { results };
};

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const name = formData.get('name');
        const id = await findId(name);

        if (id == null)
            return fail(404, { error: 'Not Found' });

        const newUrl = new URL(request.url);
        newUrl.searchParams.set('id', id);

        redirect(302, newUrl); // throw in SvelteKit v1
    }
};
```

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script>
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
    
    export let data;
    export let form;
</script>

<form method="post" use:enhance>
    <label>
        Search by name<br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </label>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

{#if form?.error}
    <p style="color: red">{form.error}</p>
{/if}

{#if data.results}
    <!-- results for search here -->
{/if}
```